# Process finished with exit code 1 pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing my own discord bot, through a lot of mistakes and errors I came to a big same error, and I have no idea what it is.

```
File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\discord-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', "/users/@me"))
File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\discord-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\discord-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\discord-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\discord-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\discord-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\PycharmProjects\discord-bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 304, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001B8A2E9D000>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a HTTP 401 Statuscode (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401).

That means that the resource you're trying to access is protected by some kind of authorization. You have to pass an username and password or an authorization token in your request.

I don't know this discord-bot libary, but I guess that this lib offers some kind of authorization.